# Tapku Coverflow: Programmatically change image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, tapku

i'm trying to implement a button to increment the album art using Tapku Library and not having much luck.

I was considering replicating a touch using 'touchesBegan' but this is a bit hacky and would rather a cleaner approach.

My code to increment the image, which does not update the image is as follows:

```
(IBAction)nextImage:(id)sender {
    if(imageSelected++ < kNumberOfImages){
        coverView.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:imageSelected];
    [self coverflowView:coverFlow coverAtIndexWasBroughtToFront:imageSelected];
    }else{
        imageSelected--;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where i might be going wrong? Thanks